# Respond to events in other JPanels

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

Ok so lets say I have 3 Jpanels - 1 parent and 2 Children

```
//Assume necessary imports etc
```

parent is something like:

```
public class ParentPanel extends JFrame  {
private JPanel mainPanel,controlPanel;

public ParentPanel(){
    MainPanel pp= new ParentPanel();
    controlPanel cp = new controlPanel();
}
...
```

Main Panel in real thing is like a 2d graphics thing but not important for the point so simplified:

```
public class MainPanel implements MouseMotionListener{
    public MainPanel(){
        //not important now 
    }

    public void MouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0){
        int xPos e.getX
    }
...
```

What i want to do is get the X pos of the mouse and pass it from main panel up to the parent and into a label for example on the sibling control panel.

Any ideas clues or pointers appreciated thanks

Comment: Interesting question. In general, known patterns and best practices to communicate different UI components.

Comment: Agreed, I'd like to know how others approach the problem.

Comment: apologies for arg0 e variable confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how complicated the GUI is you can pass the ParentPanel object as a parameter to the MainPanel object. In the MainPanel you have access to all the ParentPanel's components etc.

```
 public class MainPanel implements MouseMotionListener{

 ParentPanel parent;

 public MainPanel(ParentPanel p){
    //not important now
    parent = p; 
 }

 public void MouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0){
    //Access to parent here.
 }
```

And in the ParentPanel when you create teh MainPanel:

```
MainPanel pp= new MainPanel(this);
```

This is of course a very simple solution and more complicated GUIs will not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a pass-through listener.  Something in the child panel that the parent can listen too.  Then when the child received a mouse moved event it would broadcast it back up to the parent.

You could also make the label on the sibling control panel into a small model object.  Then both of the children listeners would know about the model object.  One child would modify it and the other would listen for updates.

Comment: Sorry dont know what you mean, do you have a link where I could read up?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface that is notified of the changes which ParentPanel can then implement and MainPanel can use to pass the message along.

```
interface XPositionListener {
    void updateXPosition(int xPos);
}  

public class ParentPanel extends JFrame implements XPositionListener  {
    private MainPanel mainPanel; private ControlPanel controlPanel;

    public ParentPanel() {
        mainPanel = new MainPanel(this);
        controlPanel = new ControlPanel();
    }

    void updateXPosition(int xPos) {
        // Update a label or whatever
    }   

    // ...
}

public class MainPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    XPositionListener listener;

    public MainPanel(XPositionListener listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void MouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        int xPos = event.getPoint().x;
        listener.updateXPosition(xPos);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Check out the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for information on a more robust solution.

Comment: This rung some bells from the last time i did any java (been a while) and im sure its the proper way to go but as it isnt too complicated going for the one above